# Windows Universal App Error System.IO.FileSystem - Cordova

Tags: c#, cordova, uwp, win-universal-app, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use two different windows UWP project in a Windows 10 cordova app. Both projects produce the same error. The code in one of the projects is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace DiskSpaceLibrary
{
    public sealed class DiskSpace
    {

        internal static readonly StorageFolder[] APP_FOLDERS = {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,
            ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder,
            ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder
        };

        [DataContract]
        internal class Result
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal ulong app = 0;
            [DataMember]
            internal ulong total = 0;
            [DataMember]
            internal ulong free = 0;
        }

        // Manually compute total size of the given StorageFolder
        private static ulong sizeFolder(StorageFolder folder)
        {
            ulong folderSize = 0;
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder.Path);

                // Get back a prefilled (with size) list of files contained in given folder
                foreach (var fileInfo in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    folderSize += (ulong)fileInfo.Length;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return 0;
            }
            return folderSize;
        }

        // Return the system FreeSpace and Capacity properties
        private async static Task<IDictionary<string, object>> getExtraProperties()
        {
            var basicProperties = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            return await basicProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { "System.FreeSpace", "System.Capacity" });
        }

        // Class Entry point 
        public static IAsyncOperation<string> info(string args)
        {
            // Entry point in WinRT can not return Task<T> - so here is a trick to convert IAsyncOperation (WinRT) into classic C# async
            return infoTask().AsAsyncOperation();
        }

        // The real disk space work is done here within some asynchronous stuff
        private async static Task<string> infoTask()
        {
            Result result = new Result();

            // Run folder discovery into another Thread to not block UI Thread
            await Task.Run(() => {

                foreach (var folder in APP_FOLDERS)
                {
                    result.app += sizeFolder(folder);
                }
            });

            await getExtraProperties().ContinueWith(propertiesTask =>
            {
                result.free = (ulong)propertiesTask.Result["System.FreeSpace"];
                result.total = (ulong)propertiesTask.Result["System.Capacity"];
            });

            // Return JSON Result
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
            MemoryStream outputMs = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(outputMs, result);

            outputMs.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputMs);

            return sr.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
}
```

This project is from https://github.com/sqli/sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin

It simply looks for used disk space and reports the used and available space using the System.IO.DirectoryInfo and the async methods to get the free space and capacity.

When I build this is it generates the winmd files no problems, I have correctly registered and loaded these in my cordova (Visual Studio 2017) project, Build for Windows 10 and run - when I run this code in the main cordova project

```
DiskSpacePlugin.info({}, function (ok) { console.log(ok); }, function (err) { console.log(err); });
```

I get this result in the console

```
WinRTError: The system cannot find the file specified.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.sizeFolder(StorageFolder folder)
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<infoTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.Ex
console-via-logger.js (173,15)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      asyncOpCausalityId: 461,
      asyncOpSource: { },
      asyncOpType: "Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1<String>",
      description: "The system cannot find the file specified.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.sizeFolder(StorageFolder folder)
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<infoTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.Ex",
      message: "The system cannot find the file specified.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.sizeFolder(StorageFolder folder)
   at DiskSpaceLibrary.DiskSpace.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<infoTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.Ex",
      name: "WinRTError",
      number: -2147024894
   }
```

I have also tried another module for unzipping files in a cordova windows 10 project (I do not have the source for this one however it comes from https://github.com/Culture22/cordova-windows10-zip) and it comes up with exactly the same error messages when I try to run it within the app.

I have googled and looked for this issue for the last 4 days and I am unable to progress, the methods being used are all support by the framework apparently looking at (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185496.aspx) - does anyone have any insight?

Comment: System.IO.FileSystem isn't part of the framework its a nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/

Comment: Yes I understand that and have even loaded it into the project but it should not even be using it according to the MS documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the library you're referencing references the System.IO.FileSystem.dll, however for whatever reason its not getting deployed with your application. I suggest try adding a nuget reference to System.IO.FileSystem.dll to your application.

Comment: I believe Cordova 7 which creates Windows 10 UWP apps in a thing called remote mode - which it seems does not support including additional libraries. Still working on this whole thing but was able to compile and run the above atfter I removed the external libs and use UWP poor libs instead like Windows.Data.Json for serialisation and taking out the loop through the folders using DIrectoryInfo and instead using Windows.Storage.FileProperties.BasicProperties basicProperties =
                            await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync(); - I cannot work out how to get around this.

Comment: I have just found this comment on another question: Cordova UWP apps can use only NetCore, not the full .Net Framework, whether they are direct .Net apps or call .Net inside a WRC